# Ext Js Ext.util.TaskRunner running only when the page is focused

Tags: javascript, extjs

We are using the ExtJS TaskRunner to auto-logout our users when they are inactive for a certain amount of time. Here's the code for creating and starting the task:

```js
this.timeoutInSec = 20 * 60;
this.runner = new Ext.util.TaskRunner();
this.autoLogoutTask = this.runner.newTask({
    run: this.checkTimeout,
    interval: this.checkInterval,
    addCountToArgs: true,
    scope: this
});
this.firstWarningDisplay = false;
this.secondWarningDisplay = false;
this.autoLogoutTask.start();
```

Each minute we display in the console: "Session will expire in 19 min". If the page is not active in Chrome, the clock stops, and when we come back to the page it resumes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because JS timers (setIntervals and setTimeout) are throttled by browsers when tab in inactive to improve performance.

[Heavy throttling of chained JS timers beginning in Chrome 88](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/timer-throttling-in-chrome-88/)

It's not an issue with the TaskRunner, even if you try setInterval, you will get same results.

Consider implementing WebSocket and move your timers to the server, and send the state from client.